# Add a product type condition to a shopping cart rule

Tags: admin, cart-rule, ee-1.12

We have a cart rule that is applied based on total product quantity in cart. It seems however that configurable products are counted as double quantity.

I would like to filter out configurable products from the rule therefore. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The **only** two actions that can be applied are based on `Attribute Set` and `Category`.

[image]

Outside of writing a module to inject this functionality, I suggest doing the following:

- Apply or make use of **specific attribute sets** for each **product type**.
- Create 'hidden' categories (set the 'Is Active' flag to `No`) that are used specifically for promotions. These categories would mirror the **product type**, E.g. Promotions > Simple or Promotions > Configurable.

Option 2 requires you to place the products themselves into the categories, which can be done with a batch update script or with Dataflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feared so. Seems a bit of a stupid thing of the cart rule imho. Thanks for the tips. I guess I can also make my own product attribute then that mirrors product type and use that (also possible with the option 'use for promo rules') :-)

Comment: Absolutely - that's totally an option.

Comment: Luckily found something easier :-) The configurable subproducts were all Visibility 'not individually visible' so I could filter on this property to solve the problem. But imho it's magento's fault that it's so unclear that Configurable products are counted twice. I mean what the ..